# AWS Redshift: Manage Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to assign one snapshot in my A AWS account to B AWS account as root user in A account.

But the button "Manage Access" is always dark.

Why is that? How can I do with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [Amazon EBS Snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html), then access can be granted to a different AWS account by:

- Selecting the snapshot in the EC2 management console
- Clicking **Edit** in the **Permissions** sub-tab at the bottom OR by selecting **Modify Permissions** in the **Actions** menu
- An AWS Account number can then be entered

If you are unable to select **Modify Permissions**, then you probably have insufficient permissions associated with your IAM User.